# Detecting browser and replacing web part?

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, video

I have a video I want to display on my SharePoint 2010 public facing site and at the moment I am using Silverlight, however, I would like to replace this with flash (youtube actually) if the users are using an unsupported browser which I am guessing is anything other than IE.

Anyone know of a web part that would do this or a little Javascript / JQuery?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Matthew Hughes

Comment: Nitpick: Your guess is wrong in that on Windows, Silverlight works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari as well. Also apparently on OS X, but reports of that are varying. If it doesn't work in anything other than IE, it's not really Silverlight's fault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahh, now I see what you're doing. While your approach will work, I tend to prefer the "use a supported method for everyone" approach. The issue with doing this client side is that even if you remove the Silverlight container with Javascript, the browser is still initially going to try and load it.

This is one of my gripes with the SharePoint team; while I understand that Silverlight is a Microsoft product, they've put so much work into making SharePoint 2010 cross browser compatible, but they're still grasping onto the straw that is Silverlight. A nice cross browser compatible video web part would have been far more useful.

All that said, in my opinion, you're better off ditching the Silverlight component, and using something like [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) in a Content Editor Web Part. It's certainly a bit more "work" to get stood up than just dragging in a web part, but it handles everything cross browser, unlike the OOTB Silverlight player.

Comment: Just to add too, there's a great post here that discusses a bunch of HTML5 video players, and which ones work on the iPad and what the features are: http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/01/pick-the-perfect-html5-video-player-for-your-site/

Comment: If you dump VideoJS into a CEWP, then Export it, modify the .webpart definition to make it more defined (ie, set the Title, etc), and upload into the Web Part Gallery, you have a pre-configured web part good to go! :)

Comment: Very good point James. I've also done a few implementations where I've used SPServices to read from a "Video Playlist" list, to build a playlist attached to the player.

Comment: Cant speak for any other video player but I suggest flowplayer as well, which suprisingly is missing from the list on webmonkey.

I'd recommend it as it just worked and was easy to incorporate and skin.

Comment: Flowplayer was actually the one I used last time I did this, but couldn't remember the name (youdaman BinaryJam). It is one of the easiest to integrate I've seen... great support too (and it has a slick little customization wizard). http://flowplayer.org